# Unable to load .bash_profile or .bashrc when running VSCode tasks on windows 10

Tags: windows, bash, shell, terminal, visual-studio-code

I am using `VSCode` version `1.31.0` on Windows 10 Home. I have enabled WSL, and installed couple of things like nvm, pyenv, and etc. which requires additional scripts needed to run on `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile`

For example in `.bashrc`:

```
export PATH="/custom/path:$PATH"
```

When running integrated shell (`` CTRL + ` ``), everything works fine, as I can see the `$PATH` includes `/custom/path`

But when I try to run a task scripts (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#vscode)

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "eslint",
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$eslint-stylish"
            ]
        },
        {
            "label": "Run tests",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "./scripts/test.sh",
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "always",
                "panel": "new"
            }
        }        
    ]
}
```

The contents in test.sh

```
echo $PATH
```

When I try to run the task "Run tests", it doesn't show `/custom/path`, or in fact, whatever inside `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile` are not included.

I have even tried something like in test.sh, but still it doesn't load my `.bashrc`

```
source /home/user/.bashrc
echo $PATH
```

Below is my VSCode user settings:

```
{
    "terminal.external.windowsExec": "C:\\windows\\Sysnative\\bash.exe",
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\windows\\Sysnative\\bash.exe",
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["--login"],
    "eslint.provideLintTask": true
}
```

The question is:

How can I setup VSCode or windows to run tasks using my `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`?

Answer (score 1):

It is because of the following lines in my `.bashrc`

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in    
    *i*) ;;      
      *) return;;
esac#
```

So after I have updated my VSCode settings like below:

```
{
    "terminal.external.windowsExec": "C:\\windows\\Sysnative\\bash.exe",
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\windows\\Sysnative\\bash.exe",
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["-i"],
    "eslint.provideLintTask": true
}
```

The remaining commands in my `.bashrc` will be executed